# How to display validation errors from the server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-ui

I'm working on a contact form for my website, but I'm facing some issues with the display of the error and success messages. I'm new to PHP, so I'm sure there are errors in the code. I tried using jQuery UI dialogs and modals to show the messages, but they hid in the background due to conflicts with my CSS code. As a result, I removed the jQuery UI code. Additionally, jQuery is not working as expected.

Here's the link to the contact form code: [Contact Form Gist](https://gist.github.com/uditrajmr3/0adb194344f6794bf7255cdb849976e6)

I need assistance in the following areas:

1. Fixing the display of error and success messages on the contact form.
2. Exploring AJAX code to improve the form submission experience.
3. Checking the PHP code for any errors and improvements.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your form appears to have no `METHOD` or `ACTION` that would define where it's sending data and how. Did you mean to post this data via AJAX?

Comment: i know i haven't updated the the form method as i was firstly checking for errors. thanks for your though

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are Posting your Data, then you can use `$.post()` or `$.ajax()`. It is best to setup a script to accept the posted data and return some data to the request when using AJAX. It's also best to use JSON to do this, but you can use HTML.

**Warning**

As it is, your PHP Mail script is vulnerable to abuse. There is nothing to prevent a bot from abusing it and sending out SPAM from your script or to your mailbox. Consider adding a Captcha or some other method to prevent this.

Consider the following example. It is untested, yet should work with some minor PHP Adjustments.

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "email.php",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      sucess: function(h) {
        var dlg = $("<div>").appendTo("body");
        if ($(h).hasClass("alert-success")) {
          dlg.attr("title", "Success");
        } else {
          dlg.attr("title", "Error");
        }
        dlg.html(h).dialog({
          modal: true,
          close: function() {
            $(this).remove();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('196-1963826_abstract-color-wallpaper-hd.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: fit;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 650px;
  background-image: url('photo-1525847185619-02460ddde30d.jpg');
  text-align: center;
  postion: relative;
  margin-left: 30%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: -10px;
}

h4 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.email {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.textholder {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  align: text-align;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #00ffff;
}

.subject {
  margin-top: -05px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ftr {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.texta {
  width: 400px;
}

.submit {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  color: #1c8adb;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.submit:hover {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1c8adb;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.contact {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bgrnd {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.spnsr {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.imag {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.ui-dialog {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #808080;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 4px solid #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <h4>Send Us Your Queries</h4>
  </header>
  <form>
    <div class="email">
      <label for="email">Email-Id</label>
      <input type="email" class="textholder" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Do care to enter email">
      <h6>We'll never share your email with anyone else.</h6>
      <br> </div>
    <div class="subject">
      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="textholder" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="please care to enter a subject">
      <br> </div>
    <div class="ftr">
      <label for="texta">How would you like our help?</label>
      <textarea class="texta" id="content" name="content" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
<p class="imag">
  <img src="logo_S0a_2.ico" alt="logo website" width="100px" height="100px">
</p>
<footer>
  <div class="contact">
    contact us: +91 7782848946 <br> or email us at admin@gentlemensidea.com
    <br> &copy; 2020 Gentlemens' Idea, Inc. All rights reserved.
  </div>
  <div class="bgrnd">
    The image in the background belongs to its copyrighted owner and not me.
  </div>
  <div class="spnsr" link="blue">
    This site is being hosted at ecowebhosting. site hosting and ip address may change. <br> For any queries,complaints or updates related to website.. email us at <a href="https://www.gmail.com" target="_blank">admin@gentlemensidea.com</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```